# How do I test Function's code when it's passed as method parameter?

Tags: java, lambda, jmockit

Is it possible to test code that is written in lambda function that is passed inside the method `process`?

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JsonController {
    private final JsonElementProcessingService jsonElementProcessingService;
    private final JsonObjectProcessingService jsonObjectProcessingService;
    private final JsonArrayProcessingService jsonArrayProcessingService;

    public void process(String rawJson) {
        jsonElementProcessingService.process(json -> {
            JsonElement element = new JsonParser().parse(json);
            if (element.isJsonArray()) {
                return jsonArrayProcessingService.process(element.getAsJsonArray());
            } else {
                return jsonObjectProcessingService.process(element.getAsJsonObject());
            }
        }, rawJson);
    }
}
```

Since the lambda is lazy the function is not invoked (`Function::apply`) when I call `JsonController::process` so is there any way to check that `jsonArrayProcessingService::process` is called?

```java
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class JsonControllerTest {
    @Injectable
    private JsonElementProcessingService jsonElementProcessingService;
    @Injectable
    private JsonObjectProcessingService jsonObjectProcessingService;
    @Injectable
    private JsonArrayProcessingService jsonArrayProcessingService;
    @Tested
    private JsonController jsonController;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        jsonController.process("[{\"key\":1}]");
        // how check here that jsonArrayProcessingService was invoked?
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `jmockit`, but I think in your case the right steps would be: "run UUT method, get injected lambda from mocked dependency, run it, verify that, based on the json you passd, the right mock is invoked." The main reasoning is that you have to first verify the right `JsonElementProcessingService` method is invoked, and then that the lambda passed performs the right elaboration, by invoking it.

Answer (score 2):

Just make it testable (and readable) by converting it to a method:

```
public void process(String rawJson) {
    jsonElementProcessingService.process(this::parse, rawJson);
}

Object parse(String json) {
    JsonElement element = new JsonParser().parse(json);
    if (element.isJsonArray()) {
        return jsonArrayProcessingService.process(element.getAsJsonArray());
    } else {
        return jsonObjectProcessingService.process(element.getAsJsonObject());
    }
}
```

The relevant guiding principles I personally follow are:

- anytime my lambdas require curly brackets, convert them to a method
- organise code so that it *can* be unit tested

You may need to change the return type of the `parse` method to match whatever your processing services (which you didn’t show) return.

Comment: Actually I do need to use approach of passing Function because it's only called if some conditions fit.

Comment: @kbo a *method reference* (which is what I coded as `this::parse`) *is* a `Function`. It’s identical is every way to a lambda, except it’s named.

Comment: Your example makes the code public and as I understand you propose to test directly method parse but it's not what I'm looking for

Comment: Then make it package private (see edited code) and test it with a test in the same package. Or make it private and use groovy/Spock to test it. This is the only (and IMHO best) way to test your code.

Comment: I can't do any refactoring so the question is still actual

Answer (score 1):

Given its relatively-basic redirection logic, don't you just want to confirm which of the `@Injectable`s got called:

```java
  @Test
  public void test() {
    jsonController.process("[{\"key\":1}]");

    new Verifications() {{
      jsonArrayProcessingService.process(withInstanceOf(JsonArray.class));
    }};
  }
```